# Jade loading a JSON file and assigning to variable

Tags: node.js, pug

I have a JSON file in the same folder as the jade template.

Is there a way I can load the contents of the JSON file and assign it to a variable? (FYI - I am trying to do this outside of node.js passing render parameters, I am trying to get this accomplished within jade file itself)

I tried the code below and it does not work. Any pointers?

```
script.
  var jsonValue = include ./demo_options.json
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within the jade, you can not load data, you can load in your node.js app;

```
var data = require('/path/to/your/demo_options.json');
//
res.render('page', {data: data});
```

And in your script you can use as follow:

```
.script
     var jsonValue = #{ data }; //this part not sure if it will work
```